# Php link to contact form (DATABASEPHP)

Tags: php, html

```
        </div>
        <div class="row block-9">
          <div class="col-md-6 order-md-last d-flex">
            <form action="#" class="bg-white p-5 contact-form">
                <form class="=contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post"
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14884.226370030301!2d79.103842!3d21.150146!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x5106808b025223d!2sRajshri%20Traders!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sid!4v1566792666441!5m2!1sen!2sid" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="ftco-footer ftco-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mouse">
                        <a href="#" class="mouse-icon">
                            <div class="mouse-wheel"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-up"></span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-5">
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="ftco-footer-widget mb-4">
              <h2 class="ftco-heading-2">Rajshri Traders</h2>
              <p>We provide the best Cctvs.</p>
              <ul class="ftco-footer-social list-unstyled float-md-left float-lft mt-5">
                <li class="ftco-animate"><a href="#"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a></li>
                <li class="ftco-animate"><a href="#"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
                <li class="ftco-animate"><a href="#"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="ftco-footer-widget mb-4 ml-md-5">
              <h2 class="ftco-heading-2">Menu</h2>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#" class="py-2 d-block">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="py-2 d-block">About</a></li>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="ftco-footer-widget mb-4">
               <h2 class="ftco-heading-2">&nbsp;</h2>
               <div class="d-flex">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mr-l-5 pr-l-3 mr-4">
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="ftco-footer-widget mb-4">
                <h2 class="ftco-heading-2">Have a Questions?</h2>
                <div class="block-23 mb-3">
                  <ul>
                    <li><span class="icon icon-map-marker"></span><span class="text">Plot No 1, Nike buildings, Fawara Chouk,Gandhibag, Nagpur, Maharashtra 440032, India</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon icon-envelope"></span><span class="text"> rajshirtraders@gmail.com</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>



  <!-- loader -->
  <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>
```

*i am trying to link my php to the contact form but facing some issues please help 
the format of the cotact us is also a bit messed up after sevral attempts to fix it i coudnt 
i am using my sql for the php 
i have the php file but dont know where to attach it in the contact us page (html)*
i have tried a few solutions looking at youtube 
but nothing works 
please help

Comment: please, take out the caps lock, and post just the minimal code necessary to reproduce what you are looking for, not the whole page

Comment: done sir i removed the unnecessary codes

Answer (score 0):

That's how work php/html:

**HTML**

```
         <form class="=contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="mess" id="" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
              </div>
            </form>
```

Here user will input data and sent to contact.php, i add `name=""` and we will create a variable with that.

**PHP**

```
// ALL VARIABLE FROM FORM 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
//NOW YOU CAN SENT EMAIL
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$headers = "From:".$email . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```